# Integrating tensors on manifolds

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, manifolds, tensors

When/how can you integrate tensors on manifolds and what does it mean?

I imagine that line integrals of tensors make sense when you have a connection,
since you can uniquely parallel transport all the tensors along the path to a common point on the paths and "sum" them there, but what about area, volume and higher dimensional integrals? What is required for that to make sense? Parallel transport does not seem sufficient anymore because there are no longer unique path to a common point and parallel transport is path dependent.

Comment: Stoke's theorem possibly?

Comment: All I can think of: in the "line integral" case the object you end up with (if you don't want to fix a base point) is a parallel field along the curve, so (if you rescale to a length-1 curve) in some sense you're computing the closest parallel field. Perhaps try making this precise using some norm and it may be a more extensible formulation... it's really getting away from the original meaning of integration, though. :P

Answer (score 1):

I can't really make sense of your idea for line integrals. Using parallel transport you can more or less reduce this to the case of integrating a tensor on an interval-but how do you do that? Normally integration should output a number, and for this it really seems you need a 1-form. Given a metric, it's true that you can do better: you can integrate functions globally using the volume form, and you can type-change to integrate $(k,\ell)$ forms where $k+\ell$ is the dimension of the manifold. But I don't see how you can do better than that.

Comment: _I can't really make sense of your idea for line integrals. Using parallel transport you can more or less reduce this to the case of integrating a tensor on an interval-but how do you do that?_ it is no different to integrating vector fields, once you have them at the same point and thus in the same space you can add them and integration is the limit summations. You can also think about it in terms of components.

Comment: OK, so if you parallel transport to realize your tensor as a function $\gamma:I\to \mathbf{R}^K$, then you can integrate in each coordinate to get an element of $\mathbf{R}^K$. But this is not a generalization of the usual line integral of a vector field, which lands in $\mathbf{R}$. Is this the operation you're interested in, regardless?

Comment: I am interested in the idea of integrating tensors in general. The line integral idea is is a somewhat, uhm, tangential :) to my question. It is just something I came up with as a geometrically plausible way to integrate arbitrary tensors. I know you can integrate forms on manifolds but I am trying to see if there are ways to integrate other kinds of tensors.

Comment: Ok. It's important to know what you're generalizing, though. Your idea generalizes the unoriented integral of a function, i.e. area under the graph. It would be easy to extend this to higher-dimensional domains, just because it's easy to extend the integral of functions on the line to higher dimensions, but this is totally unrelated to line or surface integrals-so that the answer to "what dies it mean" becomes "not much." This process actually completely ignores the manifold the tensor lives on! ...

Comment: So this is irrelevant to differential geometry, and again I don't expect you can do better: there's a very precise cohomological interpretation of why integration of top dimensional forms on a closed manifold is sensible, and that justification simply doesn't exist here.